# Почему не подключается селектор

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть вот такой скрипт , которы получает данные по ajax и рисует div`ы с этими данными.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url: "regofficeajax.php",
          data: { area: $(this).val()},
          success: function(data) {
          var list = eval("("+data+")");
          //console.log(data);
          $("#search_advice_wrapper").html("").show();
                for(var i in list){
                      if(list[i] != ''){
                      // добавляем слою позиции
                      $('#search_advice_wrapper').append('<div class="advice_variant">'+list[i]+'</div>');
                      }
                }

         },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
          }

  });
 });
```

Потом я пытаюсь повесить событие click на новый селектор .advice_variant

```
$('.advice_variant').click(function(){

                // ставим текст в input поиска
                $('#search_box').val($(this).text());
                //Делаем активным второе поле
                $('#search_city').removeAttr("disabled");
                // прячем слой подсказки
                $('#search_advice_wrapper').fadeOut(350).html('');
});
```

Но селектор не подключается. Событие не обрабатывается. Почему? я не силён в JS по-этому спрашиваю.
Как зацепить .advice_variant?

Comment: где находится ваш второй скрипт относительно первого?

Comment: @Diskyp сначала первый потом второй, но оба обёрнуты в один $(document).ready .  В этом причина?

Comment: агась, именно в этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url: "regofficeajax.php",
          data: { area: $(this).val()},
          success: function(data) {
          var list = eval("("+data+")");
          //console.log(data);
          $("#search_advice_wrapper").html("").show();
                for(var i in list){
                      if(list[i] != ''){
                      // добавляем слою позиции
                      $('#search_advice_wrapper').append('<div class="advice_variant">'+list[i]+'</div>');
                      }
                }
                $('.advice_variant').click(function(){
                    // ставим текст в input поиска
                    $('#search_box').val($(this).text());
                    //Делаем активным второе поле
                    $('#search_city').removeAttr("disabled");
                    // прячем слой подсказки
                    $('#search_advice_wrapper').fadeOut(350).html('');
});

         },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
          }

  });
 });
```

Суть в том, что `$.ajax` - асинхронная функция и выполняется в собственном потоке, в разнобой с основным кодом. Весь код, который должен срабатывать после выполнения ajax запроса должен находиться в функции, которая указана в свойстве `success` параметров аякса.

Comment: Суть не в этом)

Comment: @lazyproger а в чём она?

Comment: в том что документ не знает на что он вешает. Но Ваше замечание насчет того в какой момент времени вешать обработчик тоже к месту. Просто метод .click все равно так не сработает

Comment: Просто у Вас сделано не совсем корректно) если бы это был имеющийся в области видимости элемент, вы бы на каждый из них повесили list.length событий, что есть очень плохо. Вынесите за цикл хотя бы

Comment: @lazyproger не совсем понимаю что вы хотите донести, но события без проблем вешаются прямиком на элемент. Если вам нужно, я могу это воспроизвести на фиддле. В цикле или за ним - тоже особой роли не играет. JQuery всёравно потом будет перебирать циклом выбранную селектором коллекцию.

Comment: @lazyproger хотя из цикла однозначно стоило вынести, тут вы правы.

Comment: @Diskyp да вот так все работает , но из цикла for конечно я этот кусок вынес. Спасибо!

Comment: @Dmitriy да я уже тоже, наздоровье)

Comment: @Diskyp воспроизведите если не сложно) просто раньше за события на новых элементах отвечал метод live, сейчас ответственность за это лежит на on, click это пережиток)

Comment: @lazyproger `.click()` - это шорткат для `.on('click')`, именно так и написано в документации: https://api.jquery.com/click/ Плашки "deprecated" в документации тоже нет, потому не знаю с чего вы решили, что этот метод устаревший. Банальнейшее воспроизведение ситуации этого вопроса: http://jsfiddle.net/zkh4L83c/1/

Comment: @Diskyp проверил, да, вы правы) в 3.* версиях он работает иначе нежели чем в 2.*. в 2.* он не позволял накидывать евенты на новые элементы, походу пофиксили

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавляете новый элемент в дерево DOM, и документ не совсем в курсе что вы хотите С ним сделать

```
$('#search_advice_wrapper').append('<div class="advice_variant">'+list[i]+'</div>');
```

Но у вас же есть *body* поэтому для новых элементов используйте его

Просто ограничьте его определенным селектором

```
$('body').on('click', '.advice_variant', function(){
  alert(1);
}
```